# Is this a virus in my Google Chrome and Firefox on OS X?

Tags: macos, firefox, google-chrome

I noticed that the icon in Google Chrome and Firefox on my Mac was changed when I open Gmail. Before, it was the Gmail icon, now it's something else.

Does that mean than I have some virus on my Mac, or…?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I have not installed any new addon.

Comment: Does https://mail.google.com/favicon.ico return the right one for you?

Comment: No, I have custom gmail domain: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/mydomain.com/images/favicon.ico and it returns me lik on upper screenshot. It could be that they're changing something like Tom Farrow said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,
Mine looked like this for a while, but they've changed it back.

Since you appear to be in a different locale, it might take a while to regress.